# Enumerating list after splitting - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a small list that I am trying to manipulate and organize.

```
data = ["Rose - Flower", "Tulip - Flower", "Lavender - Shrub", "Lilac - Shrub", "Magnolia - Shrub", "Daffodil - Flower"]
flowers=[]
shrubs=[]

for plant in data:
  if "Flower" in plant:
    flowers.append(plant)
  elif "Shrub" in plant:
    shrubs.append(plant)
 
print("Flower Choices:")
for new_flowers in flowers:
  if ", " in new_flowers:
    flowers.split(", ", '\n')
  x = (new_flowers[:-9])
 
for index, flow in enumerate(x):
  print("{0}: {1}".format(index + 1, flow))
```

What I am trying to do is organize this list, split the second half and enumerate only the name of the plant. This only results in enumerating the last variable. Instead of:

```
1: Rose
2: Tulip
3: Daffodil
```

i get

```
1: D
2: A
3: F
4: F
5: O
6: D
7: I
8: L
..........
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong? I don't understand why my enumerate function would only print out the last variable and print it out interrated like that. If someone can explain it'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Strings are iterable! Thus you get one letter at the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out :

```
for idx, flow in enumerate(flowers):
    print("{0}: {1}".format(idx+1, flow.split()[0]))
```

Output :

```
1: Rose
2: Tulip
3: Daffodil
```

Comment: ``enumerate(flowers, start=1)`

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with the list further, and noticed that if a plant's name is 2 words then it would not include the second word. Is there a specific parameter in flow.split() that would allow for multiple words?

Comment: If a plant's name can be multiple words and it is always followed by " - Flower", instead of `flow.split()[0]` you could do `flow.replace(" - Flower", "")`

Comment: Would you say that flow.replace(...) is the best method of approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `x` is reassigned every time you go through the for loop. After it completes `x` is assigned to a tuple containing only the last item in the `flowers` list.

As suggested above, instead of iterating through flowers to create a matching list with truncated names, you can print it directly.

```py
for index, flower in enumerate(flowers):
    flower_name = flower.split()[0]
    print("{0}: {1}".format(index + 1, flower_name))
```

If you want to create an array with the truncated flower name, you need to append to x, not reassign it.

```py
flower_names = [] # array of only flower name to be populated
for flower in flowers:
    flower_name = flower.split()[0] # splits on spaces and returns the first item
    flower_names.append(flower_name) # append to the array instead of reassigning the array

# simple print of the flower_names array for demonstration
for index, flower_name in enumerate(flower_names):
    print("{0}: {1}".format(index + 1, flower_name))
```

Comment: Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just create a list and append `new_flower` to this list? I mean you've done it before, why not try again.

```
x = []
for new_flowers in flowers:
  if ", " in new_flowers:
    flowers.split(", ", '\n')
  x.append(new_flowers[:-9])
print(x)
```

output

```
1: Rose
2: Tulip
3: Daffodil
```

Comment: This does work. Question though. How does this method compare with the others given?

Comment: What do you mean how does it compare? It's a very simple fix, therefor I think it would be the best asnwer given.